# Sort records based on nested array element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have modal something like this

```js
[{
    "_id":"",
    "document_name":"Document 1",
    "document_users" : [
        {
            "name":"Jhon",
            "email":"jhon@gmail.com",
            "added_at":"2020-12-11 10:30:01"
        },
        {
            "name":"Michel",
            "email":"michel@gmail.com",
            "added_at":"2020-12-11 10:40:00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id":"",
    "document_name":"Document 2",
    "document_users" : [
        {
            "name":"Jhon",
            "email":"jhon@gmail.com",
            "added_at":"2020-12-12 10:30:01"
        },
        {
            "name":"Henry",
            "email":"henry@gmail.com",
            "added_at":"2020-12-14 10:40:00"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I need to sort this main documents records based on particular user's "added_at" in the  "document_users". Here email id is unique in the "document_users" field.

In nutshell, sort the main documents based on nested elements.

It will be great if I get any help how to write the mongoDB query for this one

Comment: you can use aggregation with pipeline $sort like this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9X_nf7Jc6Cs)

Comment: @turivishal Thanks for your reply. It is not sorting based on the added_at in the documents.

Comment: your question is not clear, can you please provide your expected result as per your documents.